# how to stop running programs on windows 7 with batch commands

Tags: command-line, batch-file, windows-7-x64

**Can any body tell me how to stop (few) selected running program/software using batch file (.bat) in windows 7 64bit?**

My requirement is simple : I've set utorrent and few download manager program to run on windows startup. usually I need it in that way... but sometimes I need to stop all those download managers along with utorrent in order to gain internet browsing speed. Now I have to close all those programs manually one by one...!!! I want to make it easy.... if I can use some commands to stop those programmes in just 1 step, using a batch file, that would be great....!!!

Comment: `AutoIt` can automate application control and is safer to control the applications than using Taskkill to force them closed and which could cause database/file corruption in your downloads.

Answer (score 3):

FIrst, get the process id with `TASKLIST`

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq java.exe"
```

output :

```
Image Name          PID    Session Name  Session# Mem Usage Status
=================== ====== ============= ======== ============
Java.exe            1060   RDP-Tcp#8     0        81 408 Ko
```

the use `TASKKILL <pid>`

```
taskkill /pid 1060
```

or directly

```
taskkill /F /FI "IMAGENAME eq java.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the list of tasks that have to be closed using a batch file as shown below.  E.g.:

```
taskkill /im notepad++.exe
taskkill /im eclipse.exe
taskkill /im outlook.exe
taskkill /im chrome.exe
taskkill /im word.exe
taskkill /im winscp.exe
taskkill /im iexplore.exe
taskkill /im OUTLOOK.exe
taskkill /im WINWORD.exe
```

Comment: @Melebius by running `taskkill /?` you'll find that /IM **Specifies the image name of the process to be terminated.**

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Windows 7 cmd utililty called Taskkill.  You may pass it the name of the .exe that you want to terminate.

http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/29463-kill-processes-using-command-prompt-windows-7-8-a.html

Comment: The problem with external link only answers is a that when the link goes down the answer is no longer an answer. "TheWindowsClub Forum has been shutdown"