# How to close a .pyw manually

Tags: python

I have a python program that will never exit automatically. However, it does need to do so at some point. It must run without the console, so I saved it as a .pyw, but this means there is no X to click on to close it.
How do I close this manually without restarting the machine? I am on Windows, in case it needs the command line.

Comment: If you're not going to change the program, then the fact it was written in Python is not relevant ... But "running under Windows" is. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16487579/2564301 for a general way.

Answer (score 4):

You could just do taskkill /IM pythonw.exe /F if you have only one pythonw running. Type this into a terminal or create a link on the desktop or wherever you want.

Comment: (you also could implement your own "communication protocol" to close a specific program: you let the pyw write a file to a location on your pc with no content. Then you check in an infinite loop if there is a string like "close" in it. Now you can run the program and edit the file with notepad or another python program and put the string "close" in it. But this only can be realized when you can use an infinite loop. If you have a tkinter window you can replace the mainloop() function with you own infinite loop which calls root.update() every time. Anothet option is to use threading.

Comment: I wrote this as a comment because this method is much difficulter than my answer is. This is my solution if i have multiple pyw's open at the same time )

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file. The .pyw program should check it about every 1 seconds. If the file changes, run the `quit()` command in the .pyw program. But don't check it every tick, as it will fail because the file is in a 'changing' state.

Example:

```
### Do Something here...

from datetime import datetime
last = 0 #Record the last time to do checking, for now, just put it to any number you want
while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    second = now.second
    if now != second:
        ### Do checking here for example, a file called "quit_state.txt"
        date = open("quit_state.txt",'r').read().strip() ### Strip the data
        if date == "quit":
            quit()
```

Just Change the file data to `quit` and the program will stop

Answer (score 0):

you can include threading in your script to take input

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import threading
import sys

def on_press(key):
    global pause
    if str(format(key))[1]=='`':
        sys.exit()

def fun():
    YOUR CODE HERE

threading.Thread(target=fun).start()

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

this will exit your code when pressed "`"
sys.exit() will stop main thead but you need to manage in way that fun() thread also ends to end the program actually